# JQuery - Loop through DIVs with the same class and create Array for each of them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I do have many DIVs with the same class `.list`. They are filled with other divs with the ID `element`. In these `element` divs there a checkboxes and textfields. I'm able to get all the checked checkboxes' next Textfield's value. I've saved them into one Array but I want an Array for each `.list`.

That's how my Code looks so far:

```
function test(){
 var array = new Array();
    $(".list > #element").each(function(){
    array.push($(this).find('input:checkbox[class=unterpunkte]:checked').next('input[type=textfield]').val());
    });
    console.log(array);
}
```

How can I dynamcially creat an Array for each list. I don't want to have one Array where all the Values are saved. I need Arrays for each div with class `.list`. Any ideas?

HTML/PHP:

```
echo("<div class='list' name='$oberpname' value='$oberpname'>");

        while($satz != null)
        {
            echo("<div id='element'><label><input type='checkbox' class='unterpunkte' name='$satz[unterpname]' value='$satz[unterpid]'><input type='textfield' class='$oberpname' value='$satz[unterpname]' readonly/></label></div>");
            $satz=mysql_fetch_assoc($cursor);
        }

        echo("</div>"); //.list div end
```

EDIT NOTE: Added HTML/PHP

Comment: please provide the html

Comment: IDs must be unique, by definition.

Comment: @Preprocezzor:you should provide rendered html

Comment: Can you explain me the difference between a rendered html and my html?

Comment: `textfield` is not a valid input type.

Comment: so you want an array of arrays

Comment: yours is not html it is php template... rendered html is what is sent to the browser as the page source

Comment: @ArunPJohny Something like Array 1:{-checked values of the first list-}; Array 2: {-checked values of the second list-} and so on

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have to use it that way because I get all the list elements from Database...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: ID of an element must be unique, so instead of using `element` as an ID use it as a class.

You can create an array of arrays, and access the desired list of checkboxes using the index of the `list` element lik

```
function test() {
    var array = new Array();
    $(".list").each(function () {
        var vals = $(this).find('input:checkbox[class=unterpunkte]:checked').next('input[type=textfield]').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        array.push(vals)
    })
    console.log(array);
}
```

Now `array[0]` will give the values for list 1 where as `array[1]` will give the values for list 2

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. I have a question about my 'not-rendered' HTML. Is there a better way to make it in a rendered way? I used PHP because I got some values from database and filled them in PHP Varaibles.

Comment: your PHP code is ok... but when you post a question related to html we will be more interested in how the actual html might look like than the template because if you share the PHP or any other template then we need to spent time on going through that to findout what will be the actual html

Comment: The best way is to in the browser go to view source on the target page and get the html from there - that will be the actual html created by your php code